# Using HTTPClient with ESP not working

Tags: http, json, esp

I have a program running on an esp8266 that attempts to fetch json data from an HTTPS endpoint that is hosted on aws amplify (data comes from a next.js app).

I can retrieve the data correctly when I use WifiClient alone, but when I want to use HttpClient, I get this error:

```
[HTTP] GET... failed, error: connection failed
```

This is my code:

```
void Network::get_data()
{
    if (consumption_data)
        return;

    const char *endpoint = "https://.....";

    wifi_client.setInsecure();
    http_client.setTimeout(10000);

    if (!http_client.begin(wifi_client, endpoint))
    {
        Serial.println("Connection failed");
    }

    // Make the HTTP request
    String payload;
    int http_code = http_client.GET();

    if (http_code == HTTP_CODE_OK)
    {
        payload = http_client.getString();
    }

    else
    {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http_client.errorToString(http_code).c_str());
        return;
    }

    Serial.print("Payload: ");
    Serial.println(payload);

    // Parse JSON response
 }
```

My class contains these:

```
    WiFiClientSecure wifi_client;
    HTTPClient http_client;
```

The endpoint is accessible from postman and doesn't require any auth headers. Any idea what the problem may be?

Thank you

Comment: what is the value of `http_code`?

Comment: It starts off as 400. And then -1 for the subsequent requests. The 400 error is the output text I provided above.

Comment: Its always best to add more information to the question itself.